# Import array property from CSV using cypher in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to import data from csv into the graph databases. One of the property is multi-value and I am not sure how to write cypher for that.

For instance
I have the employee ID, Name and Languages(Multi-value) he can speak as the property of the node(Employee as label). Some employees speak 2 languages others can speak more than 2. I have stored languages on separate columns(L1, L2, L3).

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT   
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:/Users/emp.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Employee {ID: row.EID, Name: row.ENAME, Language: row.L1 + row.L2 + row.L3});
```

Is this right?

I am not sure about how to import this language property as array from CSV.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use square brackets to create an array, don't use `+` as that will just concatenate your string values together:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT   
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:/Users/emp.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Employee {ID: row.EID, Name: row.ENAME, Language: [row.L1, row.L2 , row.L3]});
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I atleast know how to write. I am still running into an error.. it says collections with mixed type cannot be stored. I think I have some columns in that array blank as all the employees can't speak 4-5 languages. some speak 3 or more others just 2. How to handle this situation?

Comment: I usually (when dealing with CSV) put `coalesce(row.someColumn, "")` around things.  Coalesce returns the first non-null value, which here is the empty string.  This guarantees that if the CSV is missing something you get `""` and not null.